# XPath: return nodes with specific children but no text of their own

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In the following XML:

```
<document>
<p rend="Default Style"><hi rend="bold italic">This one</hi></p>
<p rend="Default Style"><hi rend="bold italic">Not this one</hi> please</p>
<p rend="Default Style"><hi rend="italic">Not this one either</hi></p>
<p rend="Default Style"><hi rend="bold">Not this one either</hi><hi rend="italic">Not this one either because it has others</hi></p>
<p rend="Default Style"><hi rend="bold italic">This one</hi> <hi rend="bold italic">because it is all bold</hi></p>
</document>
```

I would like to select P elements that contain:

1. hi sub-elements whose rend attribute contains the word "bold"
2. no text of their own
3. nothing else

This should mean that I am only getting paragraphs whose concatenated content is hi tags with the rend attribute containing "bold".

I have tried a variety of approaches. The closest seems to be:

```
//p[hi[contains(@rend, "bold")] and not(text()) and not(*[not(self::hi[contains(@rend, "bold")])])]
```

However, the not(text()) aspect is not working as I would like. The line that has text within the P tag itself (condition #2 above) is not fulfilled.

I have tried, as other conditions:

- not(*[ancestor::text()])
- not(parent::text())

and several others.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces between hi elements are valid text nodes. Use normalize-space() for filtering them.

```
p[count(hi) = count(hi[contains(@rend, 'bold')]) and not(text()[normalize-space()!=''])]
```

Comment: I think this also works, simplyfying the last condition a bit: `p[count(hi) = count(hi[contains(@rend, 'bold')]) and not(normalize-space(text()))]`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. text() selects a node-set, and normalize-space() accepts a string as parameter. Thus, XPath converts the node-set to a string with the string() function, and this function  returns the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions